# Group policy to grey out macros security setting

Tags: macros, office365, group-policy, security-policy

I am after GPO to prevent Microsoft Office macro security settings to be changed by users i.e. restricting my users from being able to mock around with Macro Settings in:

Options  > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings...  > Macro Settings

Can someone help please? screenshot below is not from my machine but shows what I am after to achieve.

(Edit: Administrative Template files are already installed)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr6IY.png)

Comment: Have you installed the Office Administrator GPO Templates?

Comment: Yes I have. And couldn't locate any setting for that. Yet I have seen forum posts that users have said that their organisation admin had done the same to them.

Comment: For Word for Office 365, please go to `Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Word 2016 > Word Options > Security > Trust Center`. Then double click on `VBA Macro Notification Settings`, select “Enabled”, and choose the setting in the dropdown list. For other applications for Office 365, the similar steps.

Comment: @EmilyHua doing so only sets the preferred notification method - not disabling the options from further changes. As I explained above, I know how to set preferred corporate option via GPO. The problem is users can change the Trust Center Setting afterwards as they wish.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOVq4.gif) It's strange, when I enabled the "VBA Macro Notification Settings", the Macro Settings in Trust Center have been grey out.

Comment: @EmilyHua can you achieve the same for **Disable all macros except digitally signed macros**? i.e. making this option selected and then disable further changes by users

Comment: Yes, please refer to the screenshots for Word: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WivqW.jpg), [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMfoF.jpg).

Comment: For other Office applications, the paths in Group Policy Editor, please refer to this picture: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEdsx.jpg).

Comment: Thanks @EmilyHua. That answers my question.